# Creating Multiple-State Models (rectangular nodes)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to replicate the following image for my work:

[image]

I now have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sharp corners=2pt,inner sep=7pt,node distance=.8cm,every text node part/.style={align=center}]

% Draw rectangular nodes (switch sharp to smooth for different corners)
\node[draw, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width = 3cm] (healthy){healthy $(h)$};
\node[draw,below = 1.5cm of healthy, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width = 3cm](dead){dead $(d)$};
\node[draw,right=3cm of healthy, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width = 3cm](sick){sick $(s)$};

\end{tikzpicture}\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any way I can horizontally center the "dead (d)" node (as in the image)?

Comment: You can find explanations of any options in the [package manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/pgf). It's a big manual, but just search for the option in question; clicking on it will jump to its main explanation inside the manual. For instance `-triangle 60` is an arrow tip specification and `inner sep=7pt` adjusts the padding between the text in the boxes and the drawn rectangle shape.

Comment: Please see the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is with the `calc` TikZ library.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    sharp corners=2pt,
    inner sep=7pt,
    node distance=3cm,
    >=latex]
\tikzstyle{my node}=[draw,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=3cm]
\node[my node] (healthy){healthy $(h)$};
\node[my node,right=of healthy](sick){sick $(s)$};
\node[my node] at ($(healthy)!0.5!(sick)-(0pt,1.5cm)$) (dead) {dead $(d)$};
\draw[->] (healthy) -- (dead);
\draw[->] (sick) -- (dead);
\draw[->] (healthy.5) -- (sick.175);
\draw[<-] (healthy.355) -- (sick.185);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

The key bit is the `($(healthy)!0.5!(sick)-(0pt,1.5cm)$)` coordinate specification.  It first finds the midpoint between the `healthy` and `sick` nodes, then moves down by 1.5cm.

The arrows from `healthy` and `sick` to `dead` are pretty straightforward.  TikZ places them along the lines connecting the centers, but starting and ending at the edges of the nodes.

Drawing the double arrows is a bit more complicated.  The `(healthy.5)` coordinate is at the intersection of the outer edge of the `healthy` node and a ray making an angle of 5 degrees from the center of that node.  Same for `(sick.175)`.  Since both nodes have the same width, rotating up 5 degrees is the same for both nodes.  The result is a line from center to center nudged up by a bit.  Same for the arrow from `(healthy.355)` to `(sick.185)`.

Comment: Much, much cleaner than what I have. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, what does `>=latex` mean?

Comment: @Clarinetist: `>` is a key to set the arrowhead on the far end of the line segment.  There are several possible values, and `latex` gets you the filled triangular arrowheads like you see above.  There are plenty of other choices; see the “Arrow Tip Library” section of the PGF/TikZ manual.

Answer (score 2):

`xshift` was the key option that I did not know about. MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
%\begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=center}] used for multiple parts,
%along with shapes.multipart tikz library.
\begin{tikzpicture}[sharp corners=2pt,inner sep=7pt,node distance=.8cm,every text node part/.style={align=center}]

% Draw rectangular nodes (switch sharp to smooth for different corners)
\node[draw, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width = 3cm] (healthy){healthy $(h)$};
\node[draw,below = 1.5cm of healthy, xshift = 3cm, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width = 3cm](dead){dead $(d)$};
\node[draw,right=3cm of healthy,  minimum height = 1cm, minimum width = 3cm](sick){sick $(s)$};
\end{tikzpicture}\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]